# Keyboard shortcut stop working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

This happens often that keyboard shortcuts stop working like volume control, screenshot, etc., and it start working again when I reboot system. this issue started from last month only, never had this issue before. When I press "Window" button it pop-up with list of shortcuts as usual but shortcuts doesn't work.

Again as I said all starts working after reboot. only pain is that you're working on something and you want to take screenshot and doesn't work and you've to reboot.

Comment: I experienced a similar few times, Never tried to look into it, but it sounds like `ibus` related issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Elementary 5 (Hera) this can happen when `gala` (the window manager) crashes. You can recover from a situation like this without rebooting by running:

```
setsid ibus-daemon &
ibus restart
setsid gala --replace &
```

The first command, `ibus-daemon` starts the ibus daemon, which likely is needed because it's no longer running - you can verify that before running the command by runnning `ps -e | grep ibus-daemon` to see if it exists.

The second command `ibus restart` hooks into the now running daemon.

The third command restarts the `gala` window manager because it seems when `ibus` is started before it most keyboard shortcuts don't work, so we "reload" it.